# How to deal with Hot Standby replicas and server-side cursor issue

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, database-cursor

I have an issue where I need to fetch once N-tables from replica PostgreSQL database and on daily basis all rows that are edited within 45 days time. The replica is configured to work as Hot standby replica where updates to master database results my connections / transactions to be killed and DatabaseError is thrown.

I have tried to use named server-side cursor with iteration size set to 100 000, but the problem stays. I have also changed transaction level to REPEATABLE READ.

I need to write SELECT * FROM table results to Apache Avro files and move them to Cloud Storage. Due to lack of disk-space those files are needed to be moved and deleted between iterations, so this leads some extra time for the connection to be open.

Any suggestions how to avoid the:

```
ERROR 2019-02-01 15:51:25,317: DatabaseError occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 202, in export_data
    rows = cur.fetchmany(itersize)
  File "/home/userA/data-export/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 93, in fetchmany
    res = super(DictCursorBase, self).fetchmany(size)
TransactionRollbackError: terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I have also tried to do the job with Apache Sqoop, but it eventually hit the same issue.

```
with connection(connection_params=connection_params) as c:
    c.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_REPEATABLE_READ)
    with cursor(connection=c, cursorname='{brand}_{database}_{tablename}'.format(brand=brand_name,database=db, tablename=table_name)) as cur:
        try:
            cur.itersize = 100000
            cur.execute(sql)
            results = []
            while True:
                rows = cur.fetchmany(100000)
                if not rows:
                   break
                for row in rows: 
          results.append(return_record(columns=list(row.keys()),row=row, cast_types=True))

            outputpath = './exports/file/test.avro'

            if writer(schemafile=schema_file, outputpath=outputpath, data=results):
              logging.info('Write finished, moving file {} to GCS'.format(outputpath))
              upload_failed += 1 if not upload_file(storage_config=config, filepath=outputpath) else upload_failed
            else:
              write_failed += 1
            counter += 1
            del results[:]
        except ValueError:
          logging.error('ValueError occurred: %s', traceback.format_exc()) 
          cli.report(traceback.format_exc())
        except (Exception, DatabaseError):
          logging.error('DatabaseError occurred: %s', traceback.format_exc())
          cli.report(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with your query, only with your replication configuration and the duration of the query.

Replication conflicts occur when

1. `VACUUM` removes old row versions on the primary that a long running query on the standby might still need.
2. `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks on the primary conflict with queries on the standby. Such locks are taken by `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `CREATE INDEX`, `CLUSTER` and similar, but also when a `VACUUM` truncates empty pages at the end of a table.

You are suffering from the first problem.

There are two remedies:

1. Set `hot_standby_feedback = on` on the standby. Then the primary won't remove old row versions during `VACUUM` that might still be needed on the standby. The down side is that this can cause table bloat on the primary if autovacuum on busy tables is blocked.
2. Set `max_standby_streaming_delay` to a value longer than your longest query on the standby (or -1 for infinity). Then conflicting changes on the primary are streamed to the standby, but application of the changes are delayed. That means that the standby can fall behind. This technique also helps with the second type of conflict mentioned above.

You have to make your choice, but don't forget that all the methods have down sides that may be unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! This verified the options I have, which are bit limited as there's some resistance from IT-OPS to make any changes to the underlying infrastructure setup. But now I feel more confident to push changes through :)